# Factoring the expression $3x+6y+x^2+2xy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I need help with factoring the following expression:

$3x+6y+x^2+2xy$

I am pretty much clueless as to how I need to approach this.

Answer (score 3):

Make *partial* factorisation, trying to get a common factor:
$$3x+6y+x^2+2xy=3(x+2y)+x(x+2y)=(3+x)(x+2y).$$